# Как быстро проверить соответствие строки списку?

Tags: python

Сам себе придумал задачу, и не могу решить. В общем идея в том, что дан список рок групп в списке, и если пользователь ввёл хотя бы одну из них, то выдаётся надпись 'Шикарный вкус!', если нет, то надпись'Неплохо!'. Когда одну группу ввожу, то всё работает, а если несколько, то нет. Почему? И как сделать так, чтобы работало с несколькими группами(выводилась надпись 'Шикарный вкус!') ?

```
great_groups=['Rainbow', 'Ария','Metallica','Manowar', 'Queen']

st=input('Одна из Ваших любимых групп? ')
if st in great_groups:
    print('Шикарный вкус!')
else:
    print('Неплохо!')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше проверять наоборот - входит ли хотя бы одна из групп в строку, которую ввел пользователь:

```
great_groups=['Rainbow', 'Ария','Metallica','Manowar', 'Queen']

st=input('Одна из Ваших любимых групп? ').lower()
for group in great_groups:
    if group.lower() in st:
        print('Шикарный вкус!')
        break
else:
    print('Неплохо!')
```

Но нужно понимать, что если в списке есть, скажем, "[Black](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1ZoHfJZACA)", а пользователь ввел "Black Sabbath", то будет найдено совпадение, т.к. "black" входит в строку "black sabbath".

*Обратите внимание на `lower()`. Это приводит строку к нижнему регистру, в результате "manowar" и "MaNoWaR" будут считаться равными.*

Comment: Здравствуйте, что-то не то получается. Ввожу "Queen 1" и вывод такой:  Одна из Ваших любимых групп? Queen 1
Неплохо!
Неплохо!
Неплохо!
Неплохо!
Шикарный вкус!

Comment: ``else`` должно быть на одном уровне с ``for``, а не с ``if``

Comment: Так на одном https://prnt.sc/DVlsykbHaOOO

Comment: ну где же на одном, там даже линия нарисована до if

Comment: Ааа.)) я Вас понял,  да, так работает, очень интересно, спасибо)) Уже и забыл что else при BREAK  может быть))

Answer (score 0):

Как на счет такого варианта?

```
great_groups=['Rainbow', 'Ария','Metallica','Manowar', 'Queen']

st=input('Одна из Ваших любимых групп? ').split()

if list(set(st) & set(great_groups)):
  print('Отличный вкус')
else:
  print('Неплохо!')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: будут проблемы, например, с запятыми. Если ввести "Manowar, Ласковый май", то выдаст "неплохо", хотя надо "отличный вкус"

Comment: в идеале еще и к одному регистру все приводить